# Unable to install debase gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to debug code in Rubymine. It looks like we need to install `debase` first. I tried to search in google but could not find any solution.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin20]


$ sudo gem install debase
  Building native extensions. This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing debase:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1/ext
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r 
./siteconf20210301-33052-suq8dd.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for version.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for vm_insnhelper.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for method.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling context.c
compiling debase_internals.c
debase_internals.c:111:8: error: implicit declaration of function 'RHASH_EMPTY_P' is invalid 
in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
if (!RHASH_EMPTY_P(catchpoints)) return;
   ^
debase_internals.c:319:25: warning: initializing 'rb_control_frame_t *' (aka 'struct 
rb_control_frame_struct *') with an expression of type 'const rb_control_frame_t *' (aka 
'const struct rb_control_frame_struct *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types- 
discards-qualifiers]
rb_control_frame_t *start_cfp = RUBY_VM_END_CONTROL_FRAME(TH_INFO(thread));
                    ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
debase_internals.c:768:3: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void (VALUE, VALUE)' 
(aka 'void (unsigned long, unsigned long)') to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)(VALUE, VALUE)' 
(aka 'unsigned long (*)(unsigned long, unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
rb_define_module_function(mDebase, "set_trace_flag_to_iseq", Debase_set_trace_flag_to_iseq, 1);

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:337:142: note: 
expanded from macro 'rb_define_module_function'
#define rb_define_module_function(mod, mid, func, arity)    
RBIMPL_ANYARGS_DISPATCH_rb_define_module_function((arity), (func))((mod), (mid), (func), 
(arity))
                                                                                                                                         
^~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:273:1: note: 
passing argument to parameter here
RBIMPL_ANYARGS_DECL(rb_define_module_function, VALUE, const char *)
^
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:255:72: note: 
expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ANYARGS_DECL'
RBIMPL_ANYARGS_ATTRSET(sym) static void sym ## _01(__VA_ARGS__, VALUE(*)(VALUE, VALUE), int); 
\
                                                                   ^
debase_internals.c:771:3: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void (VALUE, VALUE)' 
(aka 'void (unsigned long, unsigned long)') to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)(VALUE, VALUE)' 
(aka 'unsigned long (*)(unsigned long, unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
rb_define_module_function(mDebase, "unset_iseq_flags", Debase_unset_trace_flags, 1);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:337:142: note: 
expanded from macro 'rb_define_module_function'
#define rb_define_module_function(mod, mid, func, arity)    
RBIMPL_ANYARGS_DISPATCH_rb_define_module_function((arity), (func))((mod), (mid), (func), 
(arity))
                                                                                                                                         
^~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:273:1: note: 
passing argument to parameter here
RBIMPL_ANYARGS_DECL(rb_define_module_function, VALUE, const char *)
^
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:255:72: note: 
expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ANYARGS_DECL'
RBIMPL_ANYARGS_ATTRSET(sym) static void sym ## _01(__VA_ARGS__, VALUE(*)(VALUE, VALUE), int); \
                                                                   ^
3 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [debase_internals.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1 for 
inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/3.0.0/debase- 
0.2.4.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You are likely using an ancient library or an ancient Ruby version. Add both versions to the question and link to the library's home page.

Comment: @D.SM This looks like it's being built on Ruby 3.0.0, so unless you're from the future...

Comment: Have you tried with Ruby 2.7.2 to see if this a Ruby 3.0 specific quirk? If so, you may want to open an issue for that project.

Comment: That is probably the reason then.

Comment: @tadman I have tried with ruby 2.6.0 first which did not work. So I upgraded to 3.0.0. But same issue.

Comment: I used the pre-release gem, and it worked with Ruby 3 `gem install debase --pre`. Ticket here https://github.com/ruby-debug/debase/issues/92

Comment: Same error as @TechnicalShil mentioned: macOS 11.6, ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ], with RVM use. When installing the `pre` version, it worked.